# How to show tags by popularity instead of random?

Tags: php, tags, keyword

Need a bit of help. Been searching but I haven't found the answer yet. Hopefully you guys can help!

I'm sorting user entered tags on my site. I'm using the following code to call the tags...

```
        $query="SELECT gtags FROM posts WHERE category='".mysql_real_escape_string($CATID)."' order by rand() limit 20";
    $results=$conn->execute($query);
    $gtags = $results->getrows();
    for($i=0; $i<count($gtags);$i++)
```

How could I filter the tags by popularity instead of random?? I see the order by rand() but I'm not sure how to go abut changing this to some sort of popularity, such as how many times the tag has been used in the database.

Could someone please show me what I'm doing wrong. I'm sure it's something simple and I'm just a noob. :) Thank you everyone.

Comment: Share database structure, we are not magicians.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query like this:

```
$query="SELECT gtags FROM (
    SELECT gtags, (SELECT count(*) from posts tPost where tPost.gtags = posts.gtags) noOfApp 
    FROM posts WHERE category='".mysql_real_escape_string($CATID)."' 
  ) Pst 
  order by noOfApp limit 20";
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you're not doing anything wrong. You're not doing anything at all yet. :)

It seems to me that you are actually querying tags from a posts table. It is hard to do counting on such a field, because it will probably contain a separated list of tags. If you would have a separate table that contains all tags, and a cross table that links tags to posts, you could get a list of all tags, and count the number of linked posts per tag.

In your current setup this is not possible and you will have to parse each field and keep a count.

That counting is easy enough. Create an array and add 1 for each tag everytime you find it:

```
$tags = array();
// Loop trough all records:
  // Split the tags
  // For each tag:
    $tags[$tag] = (array_key_exists($tag, $tags)?$tags[$tag] + 1: 1);
```

After that loop, you will have an array containing all tags, and the number of times it is used.